# ReactJS setState with multiple nested arrays

Tags: reactjs, immutability

Consider the following structure:

```
this.state = {
  States: [{
    Abbreviation: "MA",
    Cities: [{
      ID: 1,
      Name: "Boston",
      PropertyToUpdate: null
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      Name: "Springfield",
      PropertyToUpdate: null
    }]
  }]
}
```

Given a city ID and a value, I need to update the PropertyToUpdate property to the value.  So I would have a function that looks like:

```
handleUpdateProperty(cityID, newValue){
  // Do some things
  this.setState({...});
}
```

I have done some reading on [immutable helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) but I'm not sure how to handle the two layers of nesting.  I think it should look something like:

```
var newState = React.addons.update(
  this.state.States[indexOfState].Cities[indexOfCity],
  {PropertyToUpdate: {$set: newValue}}
);
```

...but this is not quite the right syntax.  So how can I keep my state immutable, but still update this nested property of an array item?

Answer (score 9):

You would use it like this

```
var newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
  States: {
    [indexOfState]: {
      Cities: {
        [indexOfCity]: {
          PropertyToUpdate: {
            $set: newValue
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

See [nested collections](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html#nested-collections).